# Excel 2013 - count occurrences of strings in cell

Tags: excel, countif

I'm trying to create a cell formula that will give me the count of occurrences of one or more strings in a cell.

If I have cell A1 containing 3.1.1-4
then I want my formula to return 3 (number of times either . or - appears in the cell string.

So far I have a formula:

> =COUNTIF(A1:A1,"*-*")+COUNTIF(A1:A1,"*.*")

but this only returns 2 (I guess 1 because "." appears + 1 because "-" appears)

How do I get a formula to count the number of occurrences of either string and not the presence of the strings?

Comment: `Countif` counts cells, not pieces of data inside cells. VBA makes it easy to do what you want. No easy way without VBA, though some array formula involving `Find` might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a VBA solution. It takes two strings and counts the number of times the second passed string is a substring of the first. It uses a naïve linear search in doing so. By default it is case insensitive. Set the optional `IgnoreCase` parameter equal to `False` for a case sensitive search.

```
Function CountIn(ByVal s As String, ByVal t As String, Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean = True) As Long
    Dim i As Long, count As Long, n As Long, k As Long
    n = Len(s)
    k = Len(t)

    If IgnoreCase Then
        s = UCase(s)
        t = UCase(t)
    End If

    For i = 1 To n - k + 1
        If Mid(s, i, k) = t Then count = count + 1
    Next i

    CountIn = count
End Function
```

Then for your example,

```
=COUNTIN(A1,"-")+COUNTIN(A1,".")
```

evaluates to 3

Comment: John, thanks a lot for this. I was beginning to think it would require VB. The solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula:

`=(LEN(E1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E1,".","")))/LEN(".")+(LEN(E1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E1,"-","")))/LEN("-")`

[image]

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it